# wxPython ,Change the background colour of a StyledTextCtrl

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

I tried (but nothing happens)

```
    self.txt.SetBackgroundColour ((255,0,0))
```

As said in the title I'm trying to change the background colour StyledTextCtrl. Does anyone know a method that could be used? I've checked the API docs but I couldn't seem to find one, http://wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.stc.StyledTextCtrl-class.html

(by background colour, I mean the whole writing area, of course)

Does anyone know a way I could do this?

EDIT:

The background doesn't change in the following code

```
import wx
import wx.stc

app = wx.App(redirect=True)
top = wx.Frame(None, title="StyledTXTCtrl", size=(300,200))
txt=wx.stc.StyledTextCtrl(top)
txt.SetBackgroundColour((255,255,0))
txt.Refresh()
top.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My first reaction was to call `txt.Refresh()` because I had a similar experience using wx.TextCtrl where the background colour did not update and the `Refresh()` call forced a redraw. However, it seems that approach was incorrect.

After reviewing the [StyledTextCtrl API](http://wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.stc.StyledTextCtrl-class.html), it seems like `SetBackground()` is not the function you want. My understanding is that because STCs can have multiple styles in the same box, the individual text styles take precedence over the STC's settings.

After some research I found the [StyleSetBackground()](http://wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.stc.StyledTextCtrl-class.html#StyleSetBackground) function. This modifies the default style such that the background will be red, effectively setting the background to red. You need to call it like this:

```
txt.StyleSetBackground(wx.stc.STC_STYLE_DEFAULT, (255,0,0))
```

Just remember, if you use multiple styles you may need to make invoke this method for each one.

---EDIT---
I forgot to check my code code by entering some text. It turns out that if all you do is call `SyleSetBackground()` like I suggest above, when you enter text the background of the entered text is still white, not the expected red.

A bit more research and I've discoved this is easily fixed by calling the following code after setting the background colour:

```
txt.StyleClearAll()
```

My guess is that when you create the StyledTextCtrl, it sets the text style equal to `wx.stc.STC_STYLE_DEFAULT`. So far so good. However, after this point we change the value of the default style (by making the background red) so now the text style and the default style are different. Therefore, we need to call [StyleClearAll()](http://wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.stc.StyledTextCtrl-class.html#StyleClearAll) to reset ALL STYLES back to the default style (which now has a red background).

Comment: I just added code to the question, can you tell me if it works on your computer?, I tried refreshing the widget however no progress.

Comment: Great it works! Do you know why that after you type some text, the text background is white and how to fix it?

Comment: @user1357159 A little bit more research and I updated my answer. Hopefully it works now.

Comment: Similarly, `txt->StyleClearAll();` `txt->StyleSetBackground(wxSTC_STYLE_DEFAULT, wxColor(255,0,0));` works on wxWidgets C++ API too, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

this works on my computer just fine

```
self.txt.SetBackgroundColour((255,0,0))
```

what is your OS?

Comment: Im using Windows Vista 32-Bit,  can you post the code that you tried out? I want to see if that works for me

Comment: here is my code:                                     "self.txt=wx.TextCtrl(self,-1,'',pos=(10,10),size=(100,-1))
self.txt.SetBackgroundColour((255,0,0))"

Comment: You made the same mistake I did, you assumed wx.TextCtrl and wx.stc.StyledTextCtrl operated the same way. Turns out they don't.